# How can i enable TLS v 1.2 on Picasso for loading images with https in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, picasso, tls1.2

i have implemented a solution in Kotlin from my research on stack  here

I created a custom Kotlin class which implements SSLSocketFactory class and also added the code for passing the class to the activity where my image is loaded. My code compiles successfully as there is no copulation error but its difficult to load my image from the link added.

This is the custom class Tls12SocketFactory.kt

```
    import java.io.IOException
    import java.net.Socket
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`

    
class Tls12SocketFactory (
    private val delegate : SSLSocketFactory //constructor..u need to pass an instance of SSL Socket factory
) : SSLSocketFactory() {

    private val protocols = arrayOf("TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2") //array of two version of TLS

    override fun getDefaultCipherSuites(): Array<String> = delegate.defaultCipherSuites //return an array of strings
    //a variable of defaultCipherSuites returns an array of strings

    override fun getSupportedCipherSuites(): Array<String> = delegate.supportedCipherSuites //return an array of strings

    //four parameterss..it uses it to create socket..no return value..for creating sockets
    override fun createSocket(s: Socket, host: String, port: Int, autoClose: Boolean) =
        enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose))

    //another socket no return typ..assign
    override fun createSocket(host: String, port: Int) =
        enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port))

    //no return type..reduces code by eliminating brace = inplace of {}
    override fun createSocket(host: String, port: Int, localHost: InetAddress, localPort: Int) =
        enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort))

    //no return type
    override fun createSocket(host: InetAddress, port: Int) =
        enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port))

    //no return type
    override fun createSocket(address: InetAddress, port: Int, localAddress: InetAddress, localPort: Int) =
        enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort))

    //a nullable parameter and no return type for it not to be null socket!.apply
    private fun enableTLSOnSocket(socket: Socket?) = socket?.apply {
        //if the socket is an instance of SSLSocket
        if (this is SSLSocket && isTLSServerEnabled(this)) {
            enabledProtocols = protocols
        }
    }



    private fun isTLSServerEnabled(sslSocket: SSLSocket) = sslSocket.supportedProtocols.any { it in protocols }

    }
```

I also have two functions i created in my main activity class

The first function is provideX509TrustManager which returns the X509TrustManager is below

```
 private fun provideX509TrustManager(): X509TrustManager? {
    try {
        //its a staic class calling the getInstance method which takes a params of DefaultAlgorithm
        val factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        //this is casting null as Keystore
        factory.init(null as KeyStore?)
        //referencing a variable inside TrustManagerFactory
        val trustManagers = factory.trustManagers
        //returns the first element in trustManager and cast as X509TrustManager
        return trustManagers[0] as X509TrustManager
    } catch (exception: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        Log.e(javaClass.simpleName, "not trust manager available", exception)
    } catch (exception: KeyStoreException) {
        Log.e(javaClass.simpleName, "not trust manager available", exception)
    }
    return null
}
```

The other function is finalConvert which returns an object of OkHttpClient and is also passed the method i declared above

```
//returns OKHttpClient
fun finalConvert() : OkHttpClient {
    //gets an sslcontext

    val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")


    sslContext.init(null, null, null)
    val noSSLv3Factory: SSLSocketFactory

    noSSLv3Factory = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Tls12SocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory)
    } else {
        sslContext.socketFactory
    }

           //OkHttpClient is built
   val okb = OkHttpClient.Builder()

        .sslSocketFactory(noSSLv3Factory, provideX509TrustManager()!!)

    return okb.build();
}
```

Finally in my onCreate i have the method been passed in the downloader method that is called on the Picasso object as shown below

```
try {
        val p = Picasso.Builder(this)
            .downloader(OkHttp3Downloader(finalConvert()))
            .build()

        p.load(
            "https://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/assets/img/latest/latest_2048_HMIIC.jpg")
            .fit().centerCrop()
           .placeholder(android.R.drawable.sym_contact_card)
            .error(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
            .into(img_pics)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this," error as a result of " + e.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

This is my build.graddle file. i dont know what im doing wrong

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gitapp.tlsimageloader"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    // Glide v4 uses this new annotation processor -- see https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.7.2'
}
```

full code [here](https://github.com/UncleSamTech/TlsImageLoader)

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp does this automatically for you.  Just upgrade to 3.12.12 or 4.8.0 and remove most of this code.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_3.12.x/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/platform/AndroidPlatform.java#L442-L465

Comment: i did the upgrade...from the answer there seems to be no change because the image is not loadng yet..can u give more context

Comment: Yuri please can u point out codes i'll need to remove

Comment: Tls12SocketFactory, provideX509TrustManager.  just call OkHttpClient()